# Is there a simple way to check if an object is an instance of a class whose name is contained in a string

Tags: java

Let's suppose to have 3 classes:

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}
```

This is the string containing the name of the class:

```
String className = "C";
```

What I want to achieve is an alternative to checking if an object is an instance of the class C without comparing it to all classes.

Comment: Your example makes it appear as though you don't care about packages, so that the classes `foo.A` and `bar.A` are considered equal. Is that what you really want?

Comment: And what do you mean by "without comparing it to all classes"? Show why you need to do that.

Comment: Please explain why you want to use a `String` instead of just a class constant like  `C.class`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (obj.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(className)) {
    // name matches
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an instance's `Class` using [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()). From there, you can call [`getSimpleName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()) to get `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"C"` for your three objects  (`new A()` etc.)

```java
var a = new A();
var aClassName = a.getClass().getSimpleName(); // "A"
```